# How to create a regular expression that satisfies strings containing spaces and multiple words?

Tags: ios, regex

I want to create a regular expressions that checks whether the word passed to it satisifies from a list of words.
For example :- United states of america to be searched from the list of countries that I have in regular expression America|Australia|New Zealand|China|India|USA|United states of america.

Botht the string passed and the string to be checked from can contain spaces.

Comment: I almost don't want to answer because you're not supposed to use regex for this. just loop through an array of possible answers, and check if it matches any of them. Can you generalize your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
/(America|Australia|New\s*Zealand|China|India|USA|United\s*states\s*of\s*america)/i
```

the i flag makes it ignore case.the \s* are optional spaces

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=98136